# MYSQL SELECT .... WHERE (varios valores y valores nulos)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subconsultas

Hola Tengo una base de datos en MYSQL y un formulario con 3 IMPUTS (DNI, APELLIDO1 Y APELLIDO2), necesito hacer una busqueda cuando al menos 1 de esos inputs tiene valor dejando los 2 INPUT vacios o en todo caso los 3 tengan valores. Ya intente con OR

CASO N°1 (SI Funciona)

```
SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE dni='12345678' AND APELLIDO_1='xxxxx' AND APELLIDO_2 = 'yyyyy';
```

CASO N°2 (NO funciona)

```
SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE dni='' AND APELLIDO_1='xxxxx' AND APELLIDO_2 = 'yyyyy';
```

Comment: En vez de AND deberías utilizar OR, quieres que cumpla alguna/s de las condiciones, AND implica que las cumpla todas.

Comment: Por favor, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo un dataset de ejemplo y con los resultados que esperas obtener. Esto nos ayudará a entender qué esperas de la consulta

Comment: Debes jugar con el valor de los inputs, y depende de que inputs esten rellenos, en el backend montas la query que toque.

Comment: gracias Srole pero queria hacerlo mediante SQL, Los inputs no siempre seran llenados todos, se puede validar eso en mysql, es decir que haga la busqueda con los INPUT que tienen valores y omita los IMPUT que no tiene valores.

Comment: Edu el comentario que te pasa @Srsole es la solucion, tenes que construir lo que se llama un query dinamico y solo incluir las condiciones que tenes cargadas...

Comment: si quieres hacerlo del tiron hazlo asi: WHERE (input1 = valorA  AND input2 = valorB AND input3 = valorC) OR (input1 = valorA AND input3 = valorC) OR .... Esto con todas las posibilidades que tenga el cliente. Hay que decir que la consulta sera muy larga, y puede que tediosa para la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres sacar las personas cuyo DNI no es null sería.

```
SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE dni IS NOT NULL AND APELLIDO_1='xxxxx' AND APELLIDO_2 = 'yyyyy';
```

y si quieres sacar a las personas cuyo DNI es null sería:

```
SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE dni IS NULL AND APELLIDO_1='xxxxx' AND APELLIDO_2 = 'yyyyy';
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de utilizar el OR, en ves de AND.
`SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE (dni='' OR APELLIDO_1='xxxxx' OR APELLIDO_2 = 'yyyyy');` 
con esto le estas diciendo a MYSql que verifique cada condición, es decir, Si xxxx ó yyyyy ó zzzzzzz.

Comment: Asi no te saldra el resultado esperado

Comment: Por favor @Edu27 las aclaraciones hazlas en tu pregunta así todos nos enteramos

Answer (score 0):

Tienes tres campos de input que pueden ser llenados con valores o ser vacíos (NULL probablemente). Entonces hay que probar si un campo de input tiene un valor y sólamente compararlo con el campo de la tabla si es así.

```
SELECT * 
FROM persona 
WHERE (dni        = @dni         or  @dni        is null)
  AND (apellido_1 = @apellido_1  or  @apellido_1 is null)
  AND (apellido_2 = @apellido_2  or  @apellido_2 is null);
```